# Can I force TortoiseGit to retry to unlink file while switching branches?

Tags: tortoisegit

My primary development environment is within Windows but for Git, I try to mainly use the command line for doing most things and occasionally use TortoiseGit for others (such as viewing viewing logs or rebasing).  Usually when switching branches, there are no problems when it's removing and restoring files.  But certain programs lock these files (e.g., editing CSV files in Excel) which causes minor issues when switching branches.

If switching from the command prompt and a file is locked, it'll simply notify you that it was unable to unlink the file and ask you if you want to retry.  This will give me a chance to close the program that has the lock and let it try again.

[image: switching from command prompt]
*switching from command prompt*

However, if I were to switch branches through TortoiseGit, it will have the error but will act as if the response was `N` and finish up leaving the files in their current state.  It gets a little annoying as I have to go back and manually revert the files.  I'd rather have it wait and ask me to try again, like it usually does with other actions.

[image: switching from TortoiseGit]
*switching from TortoiseGit*

Is there any way I can force TortoiseGit to halt and ask me to retry unlinking the file when switching branches?  Or is this just not a feature of TortoiseGit?

Comment: Ah I see, git.exe reported success, therefore you don't see the "failed" options. Dunno why right now...

Comment: The yes/no question will be integrated into TortoiseGit with the next (preview) release...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to TortoiseGit 2.2.3 the yes/no question wrapper (GIT_ASK_YESNO) was not implemented. Starting with 2.2.4 this will be [supported](https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/commit/22f9af2053e196407fc3a1ee2e419176d5c4cb4c), however, I don't know why after an "error" success is reported by git.exe.